# What is going on with the map $X \mapsto X^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the homomorphism $f : \mathbb{C}[X] \to \mathbb{C}[X]$, $X \mapsto X^2$. It induced a morphism of affine schemes $\operatorname{spec} f : \mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{A}$ which topologically is the identity function. How am I meant to think about $\operatorname{spec} f$ geometrically?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, $spec \; f$ is not infact topologically the identity, it does exactly what it should. It sends $a$ to $a^2$...

Comment: am I missing something? Why is it topologically identity? $(x-a)$ pulls back to $(x-a^2)$. And this is also how you can think about it geometrically: it's the map $z \to z^2$ from $\mathbb{A}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: you are absolutely right....

Comment: @Soarer: Perhaps you'd like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Zev, done. (random characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x−a)$ pulls back to $(x−a^2)$. This is also how you can think about it geometrically: it's the map $z \to z^2$ from $\mathbb{A}^1$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$.